# How to asp.net mvc 3 custom model binder GetPropertyValue propertybinder parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a custom model binder where I check if string properties are null and replace them with empty strings.

I am overriding the BindProperty method but not sure how to get the property value from PropertyDescriptor

```
    GetPropertyValue(controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor, 
                     <What should I pass for the IModelBinder?>);
```

Here is the BindProperty code

```
protected override void BindProperty(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor)
        {
            if (propertyDescriptor.PropertyType == typeof(string))
            {
                object s = GetPropertyValue(controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor, null);
                if (s == null)
                {
                    SetProperty(controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor, "");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I use this different options :

```
private static T? GetA<T>(ModelBindingContext bindingContext, string key) where T : struct, IComparable
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(key)) return null;
            //Try it with the prefix...
            var valueResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName + "." + key);
            //Didn't work? Try without the prefix if needed...
            if (valueResult == null && bindingContext.FallbackToEmptyPrefix)
            {
                valueResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(key);
            }
            if (valueResult == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            return (T)valueResult.ConvertTo(typeof(T));
        }

        private static DateTime? GetADateTime(ModelBindingContext bindingContext, string key)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(key)) return null;
            //Try it with the prefix...
            var valueResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName + "." + key);
            //Didn't work? Try without the prefix if needed...
            if (valueResult == null && bindingContext.FallbackToEmptyPrefix)
            {
                valueResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(key);
            }
            if (valueResult == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            return DateTime.Parse(valueResult.AttemptedValue, valueResult.Culture);
        }

        private static string GetValue(ModelBindingContext bindingContext, string key)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(key)) return null;
            //Try it with the prefix...
            var valueResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName + "." + key);
            //Didn't work? Try without the prefix if needed...
            if (valueResult == null && bindingContext.FallbackToEmptyPrefix)
            {
                valueResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(key);
            }
            if (valueResult == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            return valueResult.AttemptedValue;
        }
```

Hope it can help!